# Possible to create Required Check / Pull Request Status?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I have tried the above API and the Check / Status is Optional so it doesn't prevent the users from completing the pull request. How do I make the status Required?

Comment: May I know that how's the issue going now? Feel free to leave comment below if you still has any question or puzzle below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the doc that shared by Matt,

> Status policy - provides a mechanism to block pull request completion
> until the pull request status indicates success.

If you would like to make this status **required** for pull request, you need add this status configuration as a status policy. Because the required status info of pull request can **only** read from **Status policy**.

The pipeline status info was posted into pull request after you ran this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) successfully. At this moment, you need to execute another step to make this status be **required**.

**Step1:**

Use below [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the corresponding **Status id**:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project}/_apis/policy/types?api-version=6.0
```

Then you will find the **Status** id from the response body. Paste this id into txt, it is necessary for next step.

[image]

**Step2:**

Run below api to make the status you added previously to be required:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{repo name}/_apis/policy/Configurations?api-version=5.0
```

Request body:

```
{
  "type": {
    "id": "{xxxx}" \\Put the **Status id** you copied in above step
  },
  "isBlocking": true, \\ IMPORTANT! Please set it to **true** since **false** means it is opitional
  "isEnabled": true,  \\Enable this for pull request
  "settings": {
    "invalidateOnSourceUpdate": false,
    "statusName": "APIStatus", \\Specify the status name you used while you create a status
    "statusGenre": "vsts-rm",  \\Same as above
    "scope": [
      {
        "repositoryId": "2fe327b4-66f5-4ce3-9227-dfd2ec80af1c", \\Specify this policy would apply to
        "refName": "refs/heads/master",  
        "matchKind": "Exact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add blocking on the PR you will also need to add a [Status Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops#status-policy).

> **Status policy**
>
> Using status alone, details from an external service can be provided
> to users within the PR experience. Sometimes, sharing information
> about a PR is all that is necessary, but in other cases PRs should be
> blocked from merging until requirements are met. Like the in-box
> policies, the Status policy provides a way for external services to
> block PR completion until requirements are met. If the policy is
> required, it must pass in order to complete the pull request. If the
> policy is optional, it is informational only, and a status of
> succeeded is not required in order to complete the pull request.
>
> Status policies are configured just like other branch policies. When
> adding a new status policy, the name and genre of the status policy
> must be entered. If the status has been posted previously you can pick
> it from the list; if it is a new policy you can type in the name of
> the policy in the format genre/name.